# Apache gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, lamp, joomla

Server: Ubuntu 12.04 w/ LAMP
I can access the default index.html, but I created a symbolic link to a folder in my Dropbox.  Whenever I try to access `192.168.2.6/Joomla` (Joomla is the symbolic link), I get a 403 error.  Editing my httpd.conf according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74554/403-forbidden-problem-with-apache) didn't work.  I can post conf files, etc, just ask.

I've tried using chmod to allow all permissions on the files in question, but that didn't help.

Also, I deleted the default index.html to force Apache to show the www directory.  It shows, but is empty (Symbolic link doesn't show up)

Output from `ls -lSrah` (in Joomla):

```
total 7.6M
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens  865 Mar 31 18:03 robots.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 1.3K Mar 31 18:03 index.php
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 1.7K Mar 31 18:03 web.config.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 1.8K Mar 31 18:07 joomla.xml
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 3.1K Mar 31 18:03 htaccess.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  6 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 templates
drwxrwxr-x 13 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 plugins
drwxrwxr-x 26 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 modules
drwxrwxr-x 15 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 media
drwxrwxr-x  2 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 logs
drwxrwxr-x  7 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 libraries
drwxrwxr-x  4 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 language
drwxrwxr-x 10 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 installation
drwxrwxr-x  2 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 includes
drwxrwxr-x  4 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 images
drwxrwxr-x 13 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 components
drwxrwxr-x  2 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 cli
drwxrwxr-x  2 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 cache
drwxrwxr-x 10 somekittens somekittens 4.0K Mar 31 18:03 administrator
drwxrwxr-x  5 somekittens somekittens 4.0K May 25 08:51 ..
drwxrwxr-x 17 somekittens somekittens 4.0K May 25 08:53 .
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 4.2K Mar 31 18:03 README.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens  18K Mar 31 18:03 LICENSE.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 somekittens somekittens 7.5M Mar 31 18:18 Joomla_2.5.4-Stable-Full_Package.zip
```

Output from `ls -lSrah` (in /var/www/):

```
somekittens@KittensTest:/var/www$ ls -lSrah
total 7.5M
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   41 May 25 09:39 Joomla -> /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project/Joomla/
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4.0K May 24 20:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K May 25 10:08 .
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
<virtualHost indextj:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@indextj

DocumentRoot /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project/Joomla
<Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: can you go to to the Joomla folder and give me the output from `ls -lSrah` also , go to /var and do the same, i want to see the file permissions and owner for /var/www, also the log files can be helpful, if you are using apache2 you can find them at /var/log/apache2/error.log by default, reproduce the error and use grep to pipe the error.log output to get the recent errors.

Comment: Done!  The logs give me `Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/Joomla`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your server is set to not follow symlinks. Add this line:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

to your http.conf. For more info: http://www.hackersgarage.com/symbolic-link-not-allowed-or-link-target-not-accessible.html

You will also need to add browse access for others to each folder, all the way up to /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project/Joomla/. i.e.

```
sudo chmod o+x /home
sudo chmod o+x /home/somekittens
chmod o+x /home/somekittens/Dropbox
chmod o+x /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project
chmod o+x /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project/Joomla
```

Comment: I don't have the /etc/httpd directory.  I edited it in /etc/apache2, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you restart Apache? I forgot to mention, you have to do that too.

Comment: Rebooted, no dice.

Comment: Where in the config did you put it? Try putting just `Options FollowSymLinks` in your Directory stanza. Also, if you are symlinking the directory root, why not just point it at the right place, instead of symlinking?

Comment: I've added my `conf` to the question.  I don't understand the second half of your comment.  I thought pointing was symlinking?

Comment: This part: `DocumentRoot /var/www`. Why not just use `DocumentRoot /home/somekittens/Dropbox/Project/Joomla/` instead of symlinking to it? Also, I believe the second Directory stanza is incorrect. That would point `http://mysite/var/www` to `/var/www` on the local file system.

Comment: Updated Question with new httpd.conf

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3552/discussion-between-reverendj1-and-somekittens)

Comment: What if I don't have the `/etc/httpd/` folder on my system?

Comment: I found that you need both the read and the execute permissions to be set.